# javascript onclick return confirm then submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to confirm delete before submit form using javascript, i tried this code but it didnt work :

```
<a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Confirm Delete'); $(this).closest('form').submit();"> Delete</a>
```

Comment: well you are submitting the form before the confirm. perhaps the other way around?

Comment: if i add confirm before subimt , it only confirms and submit not working, but with this code it confirm and submit, but it didnt wait to press ok :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should confirm first before submitting the form. And you need to set a condition whether it returned true or false

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Confirm Delete')) $(this).closest('form').submit();"> Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the comments against the code.

```
$(function () {
    //Attach click event to the link. In this case all links
    //You might want to update this, make it more specific by using id or name or class of the a tag

    $('a').on('click', function (event) {
       //prevent the default action of the tag
        event.preventDefault();
        //confirm
        var conf = confirm('Confirm Delete');
        if (conf) {
         //you action if true
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Submit form only when user confirm it otherwise set return false. So your form will not be submitted.

```
function confirmdelete() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        // submit form
    }
    return false;
}
```